# Bootstrap.js Carousel with only text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I follow [this](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/twitter-bootstrap-101-the-carousel--webdesign-7442) tutorial to make Carousel slide .

When I define each item contain image and paragraph as  -

```
<div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480" alt="" />
    <div class="carousel-caption">
        <p>Caption text here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

it's work fine ([here its jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/urielz/5e4v3/))  .

But when I reduce it to paragraph only as -

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
        <p>Caption text here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

it stop working ([here its jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/urielz/ZHwK2/)) .

How could I make it work with only paragraph such that is slide the text each switch ?

Comment: the two links you have given are working fine please check again

Comment: Sorry, you're right. 
Repaired.

Comment: hey i have solved the issue that you asked please check out the answer

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `position` property of the *.carousel-caption* was causing the problem, without the image it goes haywire, so set it to `static`:

```
.carousel-caption{
    position:static;
}
```

Here's the demo of it working both with and without image:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/esy38/)**

Answer (score 1):

[See after removing image and leaving only paragraph](http://jsfiddle.net/GfuMc/7/)

i gave the item container class the width and height of image with a background colour to div to indicate the presence just copy and paste this code in fiddle css section and run to see the change

```
.item{
    height:480px;
    width:1200px;
    background-color:orange;
}
```

Comment: Why you leaving the images in the Javascript scope  ?

Comment: see i have removed them

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way will simply to make images that are a background colour. If you want a cleaner way to do it, you can probably achieve the same effect using CSS.